# D3.js: Attribute contains selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In `d3`, I want to select multiple elements which contain a class with "global_read" as a substring (for instance, global_read_foo, global_read_bar).
Does `d3-select` offer something like [jQuery's attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)?

When I tried `g.selectAll("g [class=*global_read]")` with `d3`, version 5.0, I got the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': 'g [class=*global_read]' is not a valid selector

Comment: It should be `*=` not `=*` i.e.  `g.selectAll("g [class*=global_read]")`

Comment: @Satpal: Right you are, and this works perfectly fine. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer, as in "d3 supports it, when you are using it correctly"?